# Arquillian gradle importer/resolver can't create WebArchive

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to test my tests using Arquillian on Wildfly 8. My project is built using Gradle tool.

My project has one dependency, and I'm trying to use my WarArchive including my dependency declared in build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss' }  
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories' }  
    maven { url 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases' }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    providedCompile 'org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:1.0.3.Final'

    compile group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-collections', version: '3.6.7'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.9.Final'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.9.Final'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-gradle-embedded-archive:2.2.0'
    testRuntime 'org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded:8.2.1.Final'
    testRuntime 'org.wildfly:wildfly-embedded:8.2.1.Final'
    testRuntime 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final'

    testCompile 'org.jboss.weld:weld-core:2.3.0.Final'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-depchain:1.2.2'
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
}

test {
    systemProperty 'java.util.logging.manager', 'org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager'

    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed'
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}
```

My test class is:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimpleTest
{

    @Inject private SingleEntity singleEntity;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment()
    {   
        return ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class).forThisProjectDirectory().importBuildOutput().as(JavaArchive.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void categorize()
    {
        assertNotNull(this.singleEntity);
    }
}
```

when I perform `gradle test`, Wildfly is staterd up correctly. However, when the test Arquillian tries to create the WarArchive it crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive com.jeusdi.arquillian.SimpleTest.createDeployment()
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:181)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:201)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:422)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:177)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.UnknownExtensionTypeException: The current configuration has no mapping for type org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.gradle.archive.importer.embedded.EmbeddedGradleImporter, unable to determine extension. You should provide extension in the services descriptor file
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.UnknownExtensionTypeException.newInstance(UnknownExtensionTypeException.java:68)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.UnknownExtensionTypeExceptionDelegator.newExceptionInstance(UnknownExtensionTypeExceptionDelegator.java:37)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.findExtensionImpl(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:279)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.loadExtensionMapping(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:246)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.ServiceExtensionLoader.getExtensionFromExtensionMapping(ServiceExtensionLoader.java:160)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ArchiveFactory.create(ArchiveFactory.java:104)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap.create(ShrinkWrap.java:136)
    at com.jeusdi.arquillian.SimpleTest.createDeployment(SimpleTest.java:26)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: why are you calling `.as(JavaArchive.class)`?  It should be `.as(WebArchive.class)`

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that

> , and I'm trying to use my WarArchive

and you have a `war` plugin, but your code is doing:

```
.importBuildOutput().as(JavaArchive.class);
```

Please try with:

```
.importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);
```

This might resolver your problem with

> unable to determine extension.